# typeahead with array list in vue js

Tags: vue.js

Here is my code, now i can show all the result in typeahead field. but something data are missing. How can i map all the data in one array?

```
data() {
    return {
        list: [],
    }
}

axios.get('list', {})
.then(function (response) {
    self.list = response.data.map(x => x.name1);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});

//Api return josn
[
{
    "id": 17,
    "name1": "Apple",
    "name2": "Apple2"
},
{
    "id": 237,
    "name1": "Orange",
    "name2": "Orange2"
}
]
```

now, my array is ['Apple','Oragne']
but i want my array = ['Apple','Apple2','Orange','Orange2']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways.  You can use reduce to accumulate the array you want.

Also, your response doesn't have a `data` field.

Instead of:

```
self.list = response.data.map(x => x.name1);
```

Use:

```
self.list = response.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc.push(item.name1);
    acc.push(item.name2);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/h6v3mo9f/4/

Comment: Not work for me...any other solution? How about using map

Comment: I just noticed you had a superfluous ```.data``` field reference that doesn't exist.  The reduce does work.  Check out the fiddle and look at the console out.

Comment: i got it, not more ")" before ;

Comment: Typo on copy-paste from the fiddle.  Fixed.